# Right now on click of a button a modal is opening but now on click of button I want to open a modal and also Submit values for the form

Tags: javascript, html, netsuite, suitescript, netsuite-rest-api

```
htmlString += "             <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn-link border-0 cancel-btn-v1\" data-bs-toggle=\"modal\" data-bs-target=\"#cancelSubscription_" + rowInd + "\" onclick=\"openModalPauseAtClickCoordinate(this)\">" + TITLES.BUTTONS.CANCEL_SUBSCRIPTION + "</button>";

htmlString += "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm\" onclick=\"var data = {};data.unsubscribe = 'T';var value = JSON.stringify(data); nlapiSetFieldValue('custpage_newfield', value); document.getElementById('main_form').submit();\">" + TITLES.BUTTONS.SUBMIT + "</a>";
```

How can I combine this both button into one.

Comment: If you are actually submitting a form, then that will most likely load a new page. Trying to show the modal at the same time, would then be rather pointless.

Comment: not your primary question, but: I recommend you to not use string concatenation but use a templating engine instead, as your code is basically not very well readable as long one-liners

Comment: Here's something not related to the question but an observation. Try using more of [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1):

By adding both the modal opening and form submission into the onclick event of your button:

```
 htmlString += "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm\" data-bs-toggle=\"modal\" data-bs-target=\"#cancelSubscription_" + rowInd + "\" onclick=\"openModalPauseAtClickCoordinate(this); var data = {}; data.unsubscribe = 'T'; var value = JSON.stringify(data); nlapiSetFieldValue('custpage_newfield', value); document.getElementById('main_form').submit();\">" + TITLES.BUTTONS.SUBMIT + "</button>";
```

Comment: This works but as soon as modal opens page submits and modal closes too.

Comment: you can try JavaScript to handle the form submission separately from the modal opening